# android one time login system

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I am trying to design a one time login system.

- On the loginActivity the user enters a phone number to which I send a secret code thru SMS
- On the confirmationActivity the user enters the secret code.

If the secret code is successful, I want to `finish` both confirmationActivity and loginActivity. To do that from loginActivity I do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, EXIT_CODE);
```

Then again in loginActivity I call

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == EXIT_CODE) {
      finish();
    }
  }
}
```

To test whether my system works, after registration, I click on the back button:

- Expected behavior: Not being able to go back or close the app
- Actual behavior: go back to the loginActivity (notice that it skips the confirmationActivity)

My hope is that once a user successfully registers they should never again get access to either the confirmationActivity or the loginActivity. And that when they close my app and restart it, it skips those two pages and take the user directly to the home page.

Note: It looks like the `onActivityResult` method is never called. I place a few println calls in there and they are never printed on LogCat.

DISCLAIMER: Last time I asked a question and showed a code snippet, one respondent got distracted and started talking about the snippet instead of addressing the question. The snippet here is just to show what I have tried. Obviously it has not solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be:

Instead of opening the app with LoginActivity you create a new one called FirstActivity.

In this activity you check if you have set a flag in sharedPreferences.

1. If this check is true then continue to your logged-in Activity.
2. If this check returns false start LoginActivity. After a User  has succesfully entered the "secret", you should set a flag in the sharedPreferences. Next time the user opens the app the flag in sharedPreferences will be set a you will know that the user is already registered.

Any questions? comment below

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of doing that but it still leaves the problem of preventing the user from returning to LoginActivity the very moment they complete registration (by clicking back button). +1

Comment: Solutions for that: disable backbutton (very bad solution), override the onbackpressed function and do actions accordingly or manage the activity stack eg. adding the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY to your intent or declare noHistory=true in you manifest